# "'main' arguments were dropped!" in alchemy

Tags: alchemy

Why do I get this warning whenever I compile an alchemy swc?

```
WARNING: While resolving call to function 'main' arguments were dropped!
```

Is there any way to disable or fix the warning?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know what the warning is referring to, I've never found it to be a problem.  Compiling a command-line tool via Alchemy will accept arguments to main.

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to pass arguments to main via AS3/CLibInit.  I don't think this has anything to do with the warning-- the args just don't appear to be exposed to AS3.

As a workaround I've been using environment variables (via [putEnv](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aDocumentation%3aDeveloping_with_Alchemy%3aAS3_API#CLibInit)) to pass in parameters for main to read.

Comment: I believe it is related to the error. The error simply says that main arguments were dropped and that's exactly what happens, Main is essentially overridden/bypassed, since what happens is you enter the VM's main loop and thus it's impossible (prohibited) to enter your own.

Comment: When you use a program compiled for swfbridge it shows the same error, and yet args can be passed to main.

Comment: Not seeing how swfbridge and the main loop of a C program are related...?